# Help understanding which elements are installed on which servers for SDL Web 8

Tags: content-delivery, web8, installation, topology-manager, discovery-service

I have a 3 machine setup for our Tridion 2013 installation

1. Content Management Server
2. Staging CD Server (with XPM)
3. Live CD Server (no XPM)

These machines have access to 3 database servers respectively

1. Content Management Database Server
2. Staging Broker Database Server
3. Live Broker Database Server

I am now migrating these to SDL Web 8, and I am a bit confused about what is needed where (Do I need one discovery services for each environment?). Could someone confirm or reject my understanding.

NOTE: We **do not** use monitoring, contextual image delivery, audience manager or UGC.

**Content Management**

1. On the CM Database server I will install the CM DB and the Topology Manager DB
2. I then install the content manager, and run the Topology Manager scripts on the Content Management Server

**Staging CD Environment**

1. I create the Broker Database 3 times (for Discovery, XPM and Content Broker Content) on the Staging Broker DB Server
2. I install **5** standalone micro services for Session Enabled Content, Preview, Discovery, Deployment and Cache Channel

**Live CD Environment**

1. I create the Broker Database 2 times (for Discovery, Content Broker Content) on the Staging Broker DB Server
2. I install the **4** standalone micro services for Content, Discovery, Deployment and Cache Channel

If this is the case, how does this map to Topology Manager assuming I want to be able to

1. Publish to staging and live when I press "Publish to Live"
2. Publish to just staging when I press "Publish to Staging"

Thanks in advance for any clarifications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding seems to be quite OK.

If you want to minimize the number of DBs, you could combine the Discovery and Content Broker DBs, but I wouldn't recommend that; it's more convenient to keep your content and infrastructure info separate.

It is essential that each CD Environment has its own Discovery Service (DB).

With Topology Manager, the mapping between Target Type and CD Environment has become less flexible. A single Target Type will never resolve to multiple CD Environments.  If you want to publish to other Target Types than the user selected, you can do that in a Publish event handler.

Comment: Thanks Rick, Can you can confirm that I need both the Session Enabled Content Service as well as the Content Service in my XPM enabled Staging site? Or can I just use the session enabled content service?

Interesting point on the new Topology Manager, that may cause some problems with migrations and expected behavior. Every customer I have worked on in the last 10 years seems to publish to Staging when they Publish to live.

Comment: On an XPM-enabled CD Environment, you need a Session-enabled Content Service instead of a regular Content Service. You also need a Preview Service.

Comment: Regarding migration to the new publishing model: this is known to be non-trivial and hence hard to automate. Work is being done to facilitate migrations, though.